# Not able to run a vue app on node server

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs2

Im have started to learn vue js and trying to run this [HackerNews clone](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0)

I have installed node js on windows 8 which is node v6.9.1 and npm v3.10.8.

There  are two issues

1) when Im trying to run npm command it like **`npm -v`** it gives me output like this

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
operable program or batch file.
3.10.8
```

2) when I tried **`npm run dev`** it gives following error

```
> vue-hackernews-2.0@ dev G:\vue_demo\vue-hackernews-2.0-master
> node server


npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! file C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;F:\Software\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin
npm ERR! path C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;F:\Software\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;F:\Software\apache-maven-3.3.
9\bin
npm ERR! vue-hackernews-2.0@ dev: `node server`
npm ERR! spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;F:\Software\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin EN
OENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-hackernews-2.0@ dev script 'node server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the vue-hackernews-2.0 pa
ckage,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs vue-hackernews-2.0
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls vue-hackernews-2.0
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! vue-hackernews-2.0@ dev: `node server`
npm ERR! Exit status -4058
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-hackernews-2.0@ dev script 'node server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the vue-hackernews-2.0 pa
ckage,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs vue-hackernews-2.0
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls vue-hackernews-2.0
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     G:\vue_demo\vue-hackernews-2.0-master\npm-debug.log
```

Here Im not able to understand what is use of maven :/

Please explain me this issues.

Comment: It seems that it cannot run node.exe from that path. Do you have it on that C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe?

Comment: yes @Ibrahim I have that.